# Copy a little count of bytes

Tags: c++, c, memory

How it is possible to write this more laconical but not using memcpy?

```
memcpy(pDest, pSrc, 4);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   pDest[i] = pSrc[i];
```

Because calling memcpy is not optimal sometimes

Comment: which language, c or c++?

Comment: What is 'not optimal'? Slow? Too big?

Comment: Maybe get a compiler where calling memcpy is optimal always...

Comment: `memcpy is not optimal sometimes` mempcy should be extremely optimized

Comment: So far every test I did, be it byte unrolling, memory pointers, copy by integers, memcpy beat them all...

Comment: is the range even fixed (size 4)? or is this a simplyfied example?

Comment: @JesseGood it is not optimal to call memcpy to copy 2 or 4 bytes, calling function takes time and resources

Comment: @Qwerty Your compiler, if it isn't outdated by a decade or two, will optimize the memcpy. As a bonus it will do the safe thing based on what it knows about how the pointers are aligned and what architecture you're building on. Any "clever" things you can do to optimize this will likely break on strict alignment architectures.

Comment: @Qwerty: Art already made a good comment, but in short, you will not beat the performance of `memcpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <cstdint>

*(uint32_t*)pDest = *(uint32_t*)pSrc;
```

Comment: @xmoex it copies four bytes from the source to the destination

Comment: that will anyway result in a memcpy

Comment: This seems like dangerous advice to give without mentioning that it isn't portable.  (It either assumes that src and dest are suitably aligned or that the host platform doesn't require alignment.)  Not a big deal on x86 but code like this would fail on ARM.

Comment: @john Could you tell me, why do you include <cstdint> ?

Comment: @Qwerty for `uint32_t` type's. see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/)

Comment: this is also a mix of using c-style cast with c++11 std-libraries.

Comment: This will break on most cpu architectures other than x86 if the pointers are not correctly aligned. And if the pointers are not aligned this will be slow x86 without you noticing why. Just use memcpy and trust your compiler to do the right thing. The compiler is smarter than you.

Comment: @Art doubtful statement... How pointers can be incorrectly aligned?

Comment: @Qwerty Different datatypes may have different restrictions. On ARM you cannot read 16-bit or larger variables from odd addresses. If either `pSrc` or `pDest` is a bytearray which starts from odd address, you are in trouble.

Comment: @Qwerty Pointers are usually incorrectly aligned because people are trying to be clever. Or if you mean technically? An incorrectly aligned (uint32_t *) on almost all architectures means that it's not 4 byte aligned. On some cpu architectures this is fixed up internally by the cpu (which is slow), on others this just gives you a fault (this is one of the things SIGBUS was originally intended for), on yet others the kernel takes the fault and does the fixup for you in software (this is why some software was awfully slow on OSF/1).

Comment: Please note, that, apart from not being portable, this invokes undefined behaviour with the newer standards because it aliases pointers with pointers to distinct fundamental types: the compiler is allowed to move the `uint32_t` assignment past any code that manipulates the `char` array directly! The only standard compliant ways to copy four bytes are the ones mentioned in the question (four byte assignments or a call to `memcpy()`). Sorry for the bad news...

Answer (score 3):

Here are excellent comments, but since nobody else has yet posted the most obvious answer:

Modern compilers are excellent at optimizing `memcpy`. It may inline it, or use
different versions for different data.

Measure your code performance first and draw conclusions based on that. 
If `memcpy` seems to be the bottleneck on your code, you might want reconsider
your algorithm.

By introducing your own alternatives to `memcpy` you will likely introduce bigger/slower code, 
or worse: unportable code which may break when least expected.